# Как используя js тестировать потраченные ресурсы на css анимацию?

Tags: javascript, css

Меня интересует разница в затратах ресурсов нескольких вариантов css кода.

В LightHouse и прочих программах отображается только проблемы сайта и общая скорость выполнения и я не знаю как протестировать, например, затраты ЦП своего css.

Можно ли и если да, то как можно проверить сколько использовалось ресурсов на определённые css стили?

В моём случае: как сравнить, сколько ресурсов понадобилось для анимирования n-блока с помощью css?

Comment: Если к тому же можно проверить % потраченных ресурсов(цп к примеру) то было бы идеально

Comment: Кода в CSS быть не может - следовательно, ответ "никак".

Comment: Отредактировал пост

Comment: вроде бы во вкладке resurs в браузере ...а в networks общая схема и так же кол-во использованного озу

Comment: С помощью js это узнать невозможно.

Comment: Теоретически возможно замерять (применение стилей к элементам задача рядовая, а метрики прекрасно снимаются через `Performance API`) - но сложность в создании "тестовой песочницы" в документе (у разных стилей будет разная логика применения и замера, плюс комбинации придется как-то учитывать/просчитывать/мапить). В общем, проблема заключается в анализе стилей и генерации логики, для этого придется написать целую монстробиблиотеку.

Comment: Метрики - в плане быстродействия, имею в виду. CSS-слои и reflow придется обсчитывать самостоятельно, апишек для этого вроде нет. А объем памяти под изображения, градиенты, и т.д., наверное и вовсе не посчитать.